# How do I pass argument values to a running Electron program?

Tags: node.js, electron

I wanted to pass parameter values to a running Electron program, but failed. please tell me how can I do.

What am I missing???

```
// package.json
{
    "name": "electron-quick-start",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A minimal Electron application",
    "main": "main.js"
    ...
}
```

Below is the main process file.

```
// main.js
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const console = require('console');
app.console = new console.Console(process.stdout, process.stderr);

let mainWindow

/* Single Instance Check */
var iShouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance(function(commandLine, workingDirectory) {
    if (mainWindow) {
        if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
        mainWindow.show();
        mainWindow.focus();
    }
    return true;
});
if(iShouldQuit){app.quit();return;}

// Argument value output.
console.log( process.argv )
```

Executing the above code at the command prompt results in the following:

```
CMD> npm start ARG1 ARG2 --enable-logging
[ '{PROJECT_PATH}\\electron.exe',
  '.',
  'ARG1',
  'ARG2' ]
```

New command prompt content:

```
CMD> npm start ARG3 ARG4 --enable-logging
// "There is no message."
```

On the second run, the desired result does not appear.

I want you to know what to do.

** The result I want is: **

New command prompt content:

```
// While the program is already running ...
CMD> npm start ARG5 ARG6 --enable-logging
[ '{PROJECT_PATH}\\electron.exe',
  '.',
  'ARG5',
  'ARG6' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!

The first parameter value of 'makeSingleInstance' was correct!

I had to look at the manual better!

```
// main.js
/* Single Instance Check */
var iShouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance(function(commandLine, workingDirectory) {

    // Here was the answer I was looking for!
    console.log( commandLine )

    if (mainWindow) {
        if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
        mainWindow.show();
        mainWindow.focus();
    }
    return true;
});
if(iShouldQuit){app.quit();return;}
```